# What version of Apache ActiveMQ corresponds to the JBoss A-MQ v6.3?

Tags: amq, jboss-amq

Please advise what version of the Apache ActiveMQ broker/client corresponds to JBoss A-MQ v6.3?

We are considering a possibility of migrating to the open source alternative (Apache ActiveMQ "Classic") with minimum or no impact.

Comment: 5.17.x will be fine, if you are on AWS you can use Amazon MQ (active mq version). Saves you running your own brokers

Comment: When you say "Apache AMQ" do you actually mean "Apache ActiveMQ"?

Comment: No I mean the AWS Managed service Amazon MQ that runs ActiveMQ for you. https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/features/

Comment: @stringy05, the question in my comment was directed as the OP since they referenced "Apache AMQ" whereas you did not. It was clear from your comment that were talking about Amazon MQ.

Comment:  no worries at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific version of ActiveMQ "Classic" which corresponds to JBoss A-MQ v6.3. JBoss A-MQ 6.x is *based* on ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.11, but it's been fairly heavily modified with bug-fixes, component upgrades, etc. over the course of several years spanning the duration of the 6.x product's life-span.